# Hover issue in Window 7 IE10. It works fine in Windows 10 IE11

Tags: html, css

```
.rk-adjust {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin: 7px 0;

   &__tap {
position: absolute;
width: 4000px;
height: 3000px;
top: -1500px;
left: -2000px;
  }

    &__adjustment {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding-left: 9px;
padding-right: 0;
background: rgba(255,0,255,0);
height: 34px;

&:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0);
   }
 }
}
```

When I try to hover, background color changes but extra weird lines appear on top of hovering box. Please tell me if its known issue. If not, suggest some workaround?

Comment: Please post a fully working code snippet reproducing the issue

Comment: Are you sure its Windows 10 running IE 10 versus the Edge browser?

Comment: Curious how you got IE 10 on Win 10? It ships standard with IE 11 **AND** the new Edge browser.

Comment: @Illdapt I am really sorry. My silly mistake. You are right. IE11 And the new Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem appears with Win 7 and IE10/11, then try Internet Options, Advanced in IE and set Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering. (Or vice-versa, maybe).

Hope that helps - I also had lots of problems with these effects especially in contentEditable elements.

Win 10, IE11 / Edge is fine in my experience.

Comment: I tried setting software rendering instead of GPU rendering. It doesn't work.

Comment: OK, fine - it was only a suggestion that worked wonders for me. Have you refreshed and cleared all buffers / history? Could you post a working example of the issue (I still have Win 7 with IE11 so could try it).

Comment: Yes. I refreshed and cleared all buffers/history. And, its Win 7 IE10

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure I can be of any more help - I'm surprised that you still get IE10 on Win 7 - I was forced to upgrade years ago and can't go back to IE10. (Maybe try IE11 on Win 7??) - it's an available update.

Comment: I want to make it working on Win 7 IE10 :( . Btw, thanks for your response.